# Visual Studio Code Error for CSS for no reason

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

This is probably very trivial - but I am learning css and getting a bunch of errors on Visual Studio Code, but the code is working perfectly. I have tried removing extensions, and nothing is working. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hover over the red squiggles to see what the error is, the `"*"` rule is an expensive rule, better not use it if possible

Comment: `margin: 0` ..... and..... where's the `;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `;` in line 3
It's really CSS error. It's not a vscode bug

Comment: It's a typo. Not going to help specifically anyone.